# How to add escape character with str_replace?

Tags: r, stringr

How to add escape character with `stringr::str_replace()`, `stringr::str_replace_all()`?

I need to replace characters such as `'` or `"` in a string with `\'` (`Can't` -> `Can\'t`), but trying `str_replace("Can't", "'", ("\'"))` didn't work.

Comment: Surely a duplicate but you can do `stringr::str_replace("Can't", "'", ("\\\\'")) `

Comment: @sindri_baldur maybe also wrap it in `cat()` so they can see the actual output

Comment: Sorry for possible duplicate, when I tried that the result was `Can\\'t` (with double backslash). I just realized it is still OK and working fine in my case. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra parentheses around the third argument in your function call `str_replace("Can't", "'", ("\'"))` do nothing. Instead, you need to *escape the backslash*, since it is a special character in R string literals. Furthermore, since it is also a special character in the `str_replace` replacement string, you need to escape it *twice* (`\` → `\\` → `\\\\`):

```
str_replace("Can't", "'", "\\\\'")
```